# Can four lines be perpendicular

Tags: geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

Since in 2D two lines can be perpendicular and in 3D three lines can be perpendicular, what about 4D?

Is it possible to have four perpendicular lines in an n-dimensional space?

Comment: I believe the axes are perpendicular, so yes. That is, the lines generated by the basis vectors $e_1, e_2, e_3, \ldots, e_n$ are perpendicular.

Answer (score 3):

Generally in $\mathbb R^n$ you can have $n$ (and not more) lines determined by the vectors
$$(1,0,0,\ldots0),\ (0,1,0,\ldots,0),\ \ldots\ ,(0,\ldots,0,1)$$
where each $2$ are perpenticular as their dot product is always $0$.

The dot product condition follows from the generalized version of the [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Inner_product_spaces) in vector spaces which says that vectors $u,v$ are perpendicular if $\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2=\|u-v\|^2\Longleftrightarrow u\cdot v=0$ because $\|u-v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2-2u\cdot v$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, two "lines" are perpendicular if they are spanned by two orthogonal vectors.  Vectors "in 4-D" have 4 components, and they are orthogonal if their dot product is zero.  As others have noted, one example of four mutually orthogonal vectors is:

<1, 0, 0, 0>

<0, 1, 0, 0>

<0, 0, 1, 0>

<0, 0, 0, 1>

In N dimensions, we can have up to N mutually orthogonal lines.